# tcp implentation in ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am defining TCP/IP servers in the ROS node.
At the same time I want to subscribe to topic also.
What I am finding is, once enabled subscribing of topic, I am not able to send/receive data on the sockets I am using.
I am using 6001 and 6002 socket numbers for my own sockets.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262114/tcp-implentation-in-ros/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you error checking your sockets? Is this threaded? You might check here for inspiration:

https://github.com/allenh1/vanderbilt-ros-pkg/tree/master/tcp_command/src

I did this a while back.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0